# Graphical visualization of complex data using Chord Diagram or Hierarchical Edge Bundling with R

Tags: r

I have a complex dataset containing multiple row. I show you and extract that I have managed on order to plot the data using the Chord Diagram or Hierarchical Edge Bundling.

I have Two column:

```
Target;Compound
UGT;comp1
UGT;comp34
GST;comp34
NAT;comp4
ALPP;comp23
NAT;comp23
UGT;comp4
GST;comp2
NAT;comp78
NAT;comp2
ALPP;comp3
CBR;comp3
ALPP;comp58
```

I'd like to visualize a plot like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSRLY.png). In particular each node is a Different Target (UGT, GST, NAT ....), the size of the node should be proportionally to the number of the  associated compound. (es. UGT = 3, GST =2, CBR=1 ...) and the connection proprotionally to the number of cmpound that are shared. The connection should be visualize only in one direction. If a compounds is share by two target this target should be connected and the size of the arrow should be proprotuonally to the number of shared compounds bwtweeen this two targets.

In others words I'd like to see in the plot the number of compounds associated to one target that are associate also to others multiple target.
Moreover, I'd like to visualized the label of the target for each node and to color each node and related linker with a certain color.

Could someone help me please?

Below an extract of my dataset

[dataset example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1crgUNFAq-yjEdZDDhpCxAHMK9rvOr0NY/view?usp=drive_link)

[A picture to take as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqcER.png)

The picture is a graphical example that I should get, in which each node represent a compound, each color represents a target and the size of the node is proportionally to the connection that the node (compound) has with the same compound in another target group.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of your dataset. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I added the dataset!!! Thanks

Comment: @Golem Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: is this a csv file you shared ?

Comment: yes! I added in the description directly an extract of the dataset

Comment: Can you please share your csv file then ?

Comment: done!!! added a link in the description

Comment: The link is showing access denied

Comment: Try again now! Thanks